# How to generate GUID of custom length in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

sys_guid() function generating as big as 32 digits of unique id. But i need to generate uniqu id of length less than 10. Is there any way?

Comment: Use a sequence to generate unique numbers

Comment: CREATE SEQUENCE sq_test START WITH 1000000000; then use sq_test.nextval, then you get 1000000001, 1000000002 until 9999999999

Comment: @DARK_A - Thanks for your support. I need to generate this sequence per day basis. That is this sequence should reset everyday, and start from the initial value every day. Is that any easy way?

Comment: You can create a procedure to drop sequence and create it again with start 1000000000 and run it daily. Then you can reset counter daily. Try reading for runing procedure daily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642745/how-to-call-the-stored-procedure-in-oracle-with-the-daily-scheduled-jobs .